# Observable<string>.switchMap is not function

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs5

I'm upgrading an application from Angular 4 to Angular 5, and have the following code in a service

```
loadRefData(): Observable<RefData> {
    return this.participant$.switchMap((role) => {
      return this.http.get(`${this.API_URL}/${role}/participantGroups/refdata`)
        .map(refData => refData as RefData);
});
```

Since Angular 5 comes with the minimum requirement of RxJS 5.5.2, I'm converting it to use lettable operators with the `.pipe()` operator.

I thought I could do this

```
loadRefData(): Observable<RefData> {
    return this.participant$.switchMap((role) => {
      return this.http.get(`${this.API_URL}/${role}/participantGroups/refdata`)
        .pipe(
            map(refData => refData as RefData);
        );
});
```

but I get the error `TypeError: this.participant$.switchMap is not a function`. I get no compilation errors from the typescript compiler though.

`this.participant$` is of type `Observable<string>`, and unless I'm mistaken I should be able to perform a `switchMap` on it.

What am I missing?

This is with `typescript@^2.6.1`, `rxjs@^5.5.2`.

EDIT:
I just noticed that `this.participant$` which is populated from `ngrx\store.select` is of type `Store<string>`.

Comment: import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap'

Comment: `switchMap` is an operator as well so you need to use it inside `.pipe()` like `this.participant$.pipe(switchMap(role => ...))`

Comment: @Eliseo this is RxJS 5 which means operators should be imported from `'rxjs/operators'`. @martin That seems to have done the trick! I thought I had tried that already but who knows! Consider posting it as an answer.

Comment: I don't agree that we need .pipe(). I've never need it, but if works...

Comment: @Eliseo, if using rxjs 5+ you'll have to import from `operators` instead of `operator` since  [`lettable operators are imported explicitly.`](https://blog.angularindepth.com/rxjs-understanding-lettable-operators-fe74dda186d3)

Comment: @Daniel B, thanks for the clarification. Always it's learned some new :)

Answer (score -1):

Thats a quote taken from Angulars Blog, which might help you.

> HttpClient
>
> In version 4.3 we shipped HttpClient in `@angular/common` as a smaller,
>   easier, and more powerful way to make web requests in Angular. The new
>   HttpClient has gotten some great praise from developers, so we’re now
>   recommending HttpClient for all applications, and deprecating the
>   previous `@angular/http` library.
>
> To update to HttpClient, you’ll need to replace `HttpModule` with
>   `HttpClientModule` from `@angular/common/http` in each of your modules,
>   inject the HttpClient service, and remove any `map(res => res.json())`
>   calls, which are no longer needed.

Source: [Angular 5](https://blog.angular.io/version-5-0-0-of-angular-now-available-37e414935ced)

Comment: What's the connection? I'm using `HttpClientModule` and hitting the same error. This needs more explanation.